# Distribution of run time measurements

Tags: performance, distribution, measure

If we want to measure run time on a modern operating system, we are bound to get seemingly non-deterministic noise be it from the OS scheduler, blocking on IO, background threads, cache coherence protocols, etc. Now, if we assume all of these source of noise have finite mean and variance, can we make the claim that by the Central Limit Theorem the distribution of the run times is a gaussian? I've checked the answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867426/modeling-distribution-of-performance-measurements)(the author there asks about measuring run times of parts of an application not the whole application) and the closest thing to an answer I got was that, according to wikipedia, gamma distributions are good for modelling time until death. Any other take on this?

Answer (score 0):

After some debating with a colleague we came to agree that a better way to view run times was to assume that they are distributed according to a Cauchy Distribution, which has undefined (take infinite) mean and variance. Therefore, we decided that the assumption of finite mean/variance of the external noise is not sound enough. This is because processes on an OS can block/deadlock/livelock for a myriad of reasons and although unlikely, there's always a possibility for that to happen, especially if you are dealing with complicated, real production code (or in some third party library), we're not talking about toy examples. Now, the sum of many independent Cauchy distributions is again a Cauchy distribution, so we have a nice closed form of our distribution. Although the Cauchy doesn't have a defined mean or variance, it does have a well defined median, so the median should be measured instead. Also, the Cauchy has something like a "scale" parameter, the estimation of which can be your substitute for standard deviation, and there are lots of research papers on how to do that right/efficiently.

[cauchy on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)

[cauchy on wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyDistribution.html)